# DRF: appending data to each response

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

We are using Django 1.11 with Django Rest Framework and trying to implement some advanced permissioning system.

Currently, we have some tehnical issues and one of them is: return linked permissions for currently logged in user (by request.user) **on every request**.

Example: endpoint http://localhost:8000/articles/1/ should return information about that article and linked permissions to the user.
Something like this:

```
{'title': 'Article Title', 'pages': 50, 'permissions': ['can_read_article', 'can_update_article'] ...}
```

Those permissions should be managed inside Django Admin > Users & Groups system.

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you already have something that links permissions to each entity, eg a ForeignKey?

Comment: Everything is managed by Django Admin app: User is linked to a group which has permissions.

Comment: Ah, so you're not after permissions that are related to the current entity being served, but for the user themselves? That seems weird, a request for an article should get details of that article, not unrelated information about the requesting user.

Comment: The general idea is to return article's details including permissions which requesting user has. 
So, the user with Content Editor role should see "Update" button link on article's overview page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve this by using [Serializer Method Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to grab that information:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permissions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_permissions(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user

        # compute permissions
        #permissions = user.get_all_permissions() # if you are using Django's permissions, see note below
        permissions = get_perms(user, obj) # if you are using django-guardian

        return permissions
```

*Note that if you are using Django's permissions from `django.contrib.auth` which has no object level permissions, I do not thing your approach is the optimal one: Instead of returning all the permissions on each request, it would be more efficient to grab all user's permissions by a separate call and store that somewhere in your frontend to use it later.
On the other hand, if you are using object level permissions, like with `django-guardian` then this approach seems suitable.*